# Need Macro to perform formula based on cell not number

Tags: worksheet-function, vba, macros, prompt

I am working on a budget workbook and in column I (I5-I1135) I have numbers that I need to upon prompt (such as CTRL C) have the numbers divide by 10 then multiply by 12..

Example:

cell I5 has $3,266,808 (looped from other pages) and I want to upon being on this cell be able to press Ctrl C and have this number divide by 10 then multiply by 12

If possible I would like for it to go back to its original number upon prompt as well

I am using this to compare a prior 10 month year to the new 12 month budget to assure that I am looking at an apples to apples comparison

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer

Answer (score 0):

The first run of this macro will "expand" the values, the second run will restore them:

```
Dim FlipFlop As Boolean
    Sub dural()
    Dim fac As Double, ten As Double, twelve As Double
    ten = 10
    twelve = 12
    If Not FlipFlop Then
        fac = twelve / ten
    Else
        fac = ten / twelve
    End If
    For i = 5 To 1135
        v = Cells(i, "I").Value
        If v <> "" Then
            Cells(i, "I").Value = v * fac
        End If
    Next
    FlipFlop = Not FlipFlop
End Sub
```